# Subdomain to MVC url mapping - rewrite matching against multiple rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to map
`sub1.mydomain.com` to `sub1.mydomain.com/index.php?sub1`
`sub1.mydomain.com/?aa=bb` to `sub1.mydomain.com/index.php?sub1&aa=bb`
`sub1.mydomain.com/something` to `sub1.mydomain.com/index.php?sub1/something`
`sub1.mydomain.com/something?aa=bb` to `sub1.mydomain.com/index.php?sub1/somehting&aa=bb`
and these with sub2.mydomain.com too.

Whithout any redirects, just the same way as SimpleMVCFramework does it for the main domain.
The reason why is I want to use sub1.mydomain.com as an alias for the user call of mydomain.com/sub1 (which is rewrited to mydomain.com/index.php?sub1). I set the root dir of the two subs to be the same as the main domain.

Here is the .htaccess code (located in the root dir), but it falls with error 500.

```
# Map subdomains to controller
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www # if the sub is not www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(sub1|sub2) # preventing loops
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?%1 [NC,QSA,L]  
# this meant to be match if url path is empty eg. sub1.mydomain.com/?aa=bb
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?%1/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
# anytime else.
```

If I simpy use the second role, with `(.*)` pattern it matches the trailing slash (sub1.mydomain.com/index.php?sub1/), with `(.+)` pattern it matches this way: sub1.mydomain.com/index.php?sub1/index.php

Thanks in advance,
b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

RewriteConds are only applied to the very first following RewriteRule, I needed to copy-paste the conditions.